# Write to a text file inside a for loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to output text from a for loop. Here's my current implementation

```
with open('timelog.txt', 'w') as time_log:
    for x in range(100):

        time_log.write(t'/ntest')

time_log.close()
```

I'm currently writing nothing at all. The text file is created, but it seems like it's not actually being modified at all.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: That code throws a syntax error.

Comment: Did you mean to have the 't' inside the write statement? If I remove that, the code works fine for me.

Comment: Sorry guys, added the t when trying to post over here, it works without calling the close function though!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Dont use `time_log.close()` since `with` context manager will close the file automatically.

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as ff:
    for i in range(10):
        ff.write("%d\n" % i)
```

And then check the file:

```
$ cat file.txt
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: Thanks for that, worked a charm! I'll mark it as he accepted answer as soon as possible

Comment: @BGlasbey thanks :)

Comment: So that additional line `time_log.close()` cleared the file?

Comment: @usr2564301 no, it will no take effect

Comment: If the `time_log.close()` had no effect, what was the problem with the code?

Comment: @Aran-Fey the problem was an invalid syntax in this line `time_log.write(t'/ntest')`